# How to make initial data value in Vue.js single page component responsive?

Tags: html, css, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to `vue` and building a site with a `parallax image`. The transition between different `viewport widths` works fine, but I can't get the starting value inside `data` to the right value, if the initial `viewport width` is anything other than `mobile portrait`.

Right now the start value for `r_speed` (rellax speed) is set to `-5` which corresponds to `mobile portrait viewport width` which is `< 576px`. When transitioning to a larger `viewport` the parallax speed is adapted to `r_speed = -3`.

If I load in the page with any other `viewport width` though, the initial `r_speed` is still `-5`, which in case of `>576px` produces a suboptimal parallax experience.

How do I set the initial `r_speed` depending on `viewport width`? I need something like this:

```
data() {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 576) {
    this.r_speed = -3;
    return;
  }
  this.r_speed = -5
}
```

This is my `home` vue single page component:

```
template>
  <section id="home">
    <h1>Some heading.</h1>
    <h2>Some other heading</h2>
    <div id="image" v-rellax="{ speed: r_speed }"></div>
  </section>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "home",
  data() {
    return {
      r_speed: -5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onresize(event) {
      if (event.target.innerWidth >= 576) {
        this.r_speed = -3;
        return;
      }
      this.r_speed = -5
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onresize)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onresize)
  }
}
</script>
```

**Edit:**

I've tried implementing @Nikola's answer in my component:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "home",
  data() {
    return {
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      r_speed: -5
      // r_speed: -3
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onresize(event) {
      if (this.windowWidth >= 576) {
        this.r_speed = -3;
        return;
      }
      this.r_speed = -5
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.onresize()
    })
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onresize)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onresize, true)
  }
}
</script>
```

The initial `r_speed` is now correct but the transitions stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for `viewport width` at mounted hook:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      r_speed: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onresize(event) {
      if (this.windowWidth >= 576) {
        this.r_speed = -3;
        return;
      }
      this.r_speed = -5
    }
  },
  
  
  created() {
    this.onresize() 
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onresize)
  },
  
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onresize)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>r_speed:  {{ r_speed }}</p>
  <section id="home">
    <h1>Some heading.</h1>
    <h2>Some other heading</h2>
    <div v-if="r_speed" id="image" v-rellax="{ speed: r_speed }"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to remove `this.$nextTick(() => {...` from mounted

Comment: Or move it to `created` hook , like in corrected answer

Comment: One more try :), try to show `v-rellax`  if there is value in `r_speed`, look answer

Comment: Now neither the initial value nor the transition work. The initial `r_speed` is `null`. The result is a scroll speed of `0` (no scroll). The transitioned `r_speed` is `0` either.

Comment: Is ` croutonn/vue-rellax ` component that you are using?

Comment: I don't know. I have it from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-rellax). Installed it with `npm i vue-rellax -S`